# OGC WFS CQL Filter XML

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql-filter, cql

Does WFS (specifically we are using geoserver) allow for a 'CQL Filter' to be specified when making a XML request?

All the examples that I'm finding are for KVP requests.

I don't see why you couldn't do something like below yet I can't find it anywhere.

```
<CQL_FILTER>INCLUDE FILTER HERE</CQL_FILTER>
```

Comment: CQL filter is defined originally for the OGC Catologue service for web. However, it does not seem to be easy to find the documentation of that from the OGC web site. I suggest to start reading from here http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat and report what you'll find.

Comment: CQL is provided by GeoServer as an extension to the WFS standard. AFAIK there is no way to use a CQL filter in the POST requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ian already reported, there is no way to use CQL in a POST request, its usage is currently limited to GET request, and it's a vendor extension to the base protocol.

The POST request could be extended to process it of course, it's a matter of finding the development resources to make it happen. 
See here:

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer